# How to create partial dependency plot for logistic regression in Python sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

Are there any automated ways to create partial dependency plot in sklearn for logistic regression model, I see a lot of plots for tree methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PDPBox which is compatible with all Sklearn algorithms

https://github.com/SauceCat/PDPbox

[image]